# unsatisfied link error on android when using any function from <math.h> in natives (NDK)

Tags: android-ndk

I'm getting famous unsatisfied link error when I'm trying to launch my C++ based app on Android. I've tried several ways to solve this out and found out that when I comment out all calls to math.h functions (like `sin` or `sqrt`) the application launches correctly.

I am linking my .so library only with `libGLESv1_CM.a` and in Java I call:

```
static {
    try
    {
        System.loadLibrary("GLESv1_CM");
        System.loadLibrary("Game");
    }
    catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError error)
    {
        Log.e("MyGame", "Failed to launch game");
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should link it with libm. Add the following to your Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lm
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any list of Android libraries I should link with?

Comment: You can see the ones that are public in `android-ndk-rX/platforms/android-N/arch-arm/usr/lib/`, replacing X with the release of the NDK and N with the version of Android that you're targeting. They are described in more detail on this page http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#tools