# Android Studio/NDK doesn't find standard library headers (math.h)

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk, math.h

I'm trying to build an Android Project I received that also uses C++ Code. I installed the NDK via SDK-Tools Manage, but everytime I try to compile I get the following Error Message:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
Error while executing 'D:\Users\Axel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\cmake.exe' with arguments {--build D:\2016_Demo_Moeller\FloorplanDetector\Quellcode\PointCloudCatcher\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a --target tango_gl}
[1/26] Building CXX object /tmp/tango_gl/CMakeFiles/tango_gl.dir/drawable_object.cc.o
[2/26] Building CXX object /tmp/tango_gl/CMakeFiles/tango_gl.dir/band.cc.o
[3/26] Building CXX object /tmp/tango_gl/CMakeFiles/tango_gl.dir/frustum.cc.o
[4/26] Building CXX object /tmp/tango_gl/CMakeFiles/tango_gl.dir/gesture_camera.cc.o
[5/26] Building CXX object /tmp/tango_gl/CMakeFiles/tango_gl.dir/goal_marker.cc.o
[6/26] Building CXX object /tmp/tango_gl/CMakeFiles/tango_gl.dir/circle.cc.o
FAILED: D:\Users\Axel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain D:/Users/Axel/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=/usr/lib  -Dtango_gl_EXPORTS -ID:/2016_Demo_Moeller/FloorplanDetector/Quellcode/PointCloudCatcher/ext_libs/tango_gl/include -ID:/2016_Demo_Moeller/FloorplanDetector/Quellcode/PointCloudCatcher/ext_libs/tango_gl/../third_party/glm -ID:/2016_Demo_Moeller/FloorplanDetector/Quellcode/PointCloudCatcher/ext_libs/tango_gl/../third_party/libpng/include -isystem D:/Users/Axel/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem D:/Users/Axel/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -isystem D:/Users/Axel/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti  -std=gnu++11 -frtti -fexceptions -Wall -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT /tmp/tango_gl/CMakeFiles/tango_gl.dir/drawable_object.cc.o -MF \tmp\tango_gl\CMakeFiles\tango_gl.dir\drawable_object.cc.o.d -o /tmp/tango_gl/CMakeFiles/tango_gl.dir/drawable_object.cc.o -c D:\2016_Demo_Moeller\FloorplanDetector\Quellcode\PointCloudCatcher\ext_libs\tango_gl\drawable_object.cc
In file included from D:\2016_Demo_Moeller\FloorplanDetector\Quellcode\PointCloudCatcher\ext_libs\tango_gl\drawable_object.cc:17:
In file included from D:/2016_Demo_Moeller/FloorplanDetector/Quellcode/PointCloudCatcher/ext_libs/tango_gl/include\tango-gl/drawable_object.h:23:
In file included from D:/2016_Demo_Moeller/FloorplanDetector/Quellcode/PointCloudCatcher/ext_libs/tango_gl/include\tango-gl/transform.h:20:
In file included from D:/2016_Demo_Moeller/FloorplanDetector/Quellcode/PointCloudCatcher/ext_libs/tango_gl/../third_party/glm\glm/glm.hpp:78:
In file included from D:/2016_Demo_Moeller/FloorplanDetector/Quellcode/PointCloudCatcher/ext_libs/tango_gl/../third_party/glm\glm/detail/_fixes.hpp:29:
D:/Users/Axel/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include\cmath:44:10: fatal error: 'math.h' file not found
#include <math.h>
       ^
1 error generated.
```

I'm not very familiar with the NDK and I didn't find any solution to the problem yet. I tried changing APP_STL in the Application.mk but that didn't change anything.

EDIT:

Since the Project uses CMake, I guess changing Application.mk won't really help anything. Below is the main CMakeLists.txt:

```
#
# Main CMakeLists.txt
#

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)

#set(lib_src_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../libsrc)
set(ext_lib_src_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../ext_libs)
set(lib_build_DIR $ENV{HOME}/tmp)
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${lib_build_DIR})

#set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../distribution)
set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../app/src/main/libs)


set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /usr/lib)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj)
#set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -L${CMAKE_SYSROOT}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 -frtti -fexceptions -Wall")


###########################
### ADD SUBDIRECTORIES ###
###########################

set(build_libs TRUE)

if(build_libs)
    add_subdirectory(${ext_lib_src_DIR}/dlib_lib
                 ${lib_build_DIR}/dlib_lib)

    add_subdirectory(${ext_lib_src_DIR}/3dkht_toolbox
                 ${lib_build_DIR}/3dkht_toolbox)

    add_subdirectory(${ext_lib_src_DIR}/third_party
                 ${lib_build_DIR}/libpng)

    add_subdirectory(${ext_lib_src_DIR}/tango_gl
                ${lib_build_DIR}/tango_gl)
endif(build_libs)


###########################
###    ADD LIBRARIES    ###
###########################

if(!build_libs)
add_library(3dkht SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(3dkht PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
             ${distribution_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib3dkht.so)

add_library(tango_gl SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(tango_gl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
             ${distribution_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libtango_gl.so)
endif(!build_libs)


###########################
###      INCLUDES      ###
###########################

include_directories(../cpp
                ${ext_lib_src_DIR}/3dkht_toolbox/Application
                ${ext_lib_src_DIR}/3dkht_toolbox/SwissArmyKnife
                ${ext_lib_src_DIR}/dlib_lib
                ${ext_lib_src_DIR}/tango_gl/include
                ${ext_lib_src_DIR}/third_party/glm
                ${ext_lib_src_DIR}/RapidJSON/include
                #${ext_lib_src_DIR}/third_party/libpng/include
                )

#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

file(GLOB SOURCES_MAIN "../cpp/*.cpp")
#file(GLOB SOURCES_MAIN "JNIinterface.cpp" "../cpp/*.cpp")

add_library(pointcloudcatcher SHARED ${SOURCES_MAIN})
target_link_libraries(pointcloudcatcher log android EGL GLESv2 3dkht tango_gl)
```

It's also not only math.h which can't be found but also stdlib.h with the following error:

```
 FAILED: D:\Users\Axel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  -target aarch64-none-linux-android -gcc-toolchain D:/Users/Axel/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=/usr/lib  -Dtango_gl_EXPORTS -ID:/2016_Demo_Moeller/FloorplanDetector/Quellcode/PointCloudCatcher/ext_libs/tango_gl/include -ID:/2016_Demo_Moeller/FloorplanDetector/Quellcode/PointCloudCatcher/ext_libs/tango_gl/../third_party/glm -ID:/2016_Demo_Moeller/FloorplanDetector/Quellcode/PointCloudCatcher/ext_libs/tango_gl/../third_party/libpng/include -isystem D:/Users/Axel/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem D:/Users/Axel/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a/include -isystem D:/Users/Axel/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -Wall -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT /tmp/tango_gl/CMakeFiles/tango_gl.dir/band.cc.o -MF \tmp\tango_gl\CMakeFiles\tango_gl.dir\band.cc.o.d -o /tmp/tango_gl/CMakeFiles/tango_gl.dir/band.cc.o -c D:\2016_Demo_Moeller\FloorplanDetector\Quellcode\PointCloudCatcher\ext_libs\tango_gl\band.cc
In file included from  D:\2016_Demo_Moeller\FloorplanDetector\Quellcode\PointCloudCatcher\ext_libs\tango_gl\band.cc:17:
D:/2016_Demo_Moeller/FloorplanDetector/Quellcode/PointCloudCatcher/ext_libs/tango_gl/include\tango-gl/band.h:20:10: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found       
  #include <stdlib.h>
       ^
  1 error generated.
```

Comment: Did you link with the math library? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227403/unsatisfied-link-error-on-android-when-using-any-function-from-math-h-in-nativ

Comment: Are Studio and the NDK up to date? If so, file a bug at https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues

Comment: @Dan Albert: Studio and NDK are up to date. I also tried using several NDK versions (up to r14 beta) but the error remains the same, so I don't think the fault lies with the NDK. Martin K. Brown: How would I do that in Cmake?